# How to implement scalar raised to the power of a matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen3, exponentiation

I have the following code in MATLAB that I wish to port to C++, ideally with the Eigen library:

```
N(:,i)=2.^L(:,i)+1;
```

Where L is a symmetric matrix (1,2;2,1), and diagonal elements are all one.

In Eigen (unsupported) I note there is a function to calculate the exponential of a matrix, but none to raise an arbitrary scalar to a matrix power.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html#matrixbase_exp

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "Symmetric" does not mean "unit diagonal", btw. And your Matlab code does not exploit symmetry, either (nor unit-diagonality).

Comment: fair point, mistyped. Will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to raise an arbitrary scalar to a matrix power, you should use the identity  `a^x = exp(log(a)*x)`.
However, the Matlab `.^` operator computes an element-wise power. If you want the same in Eigen, use the corresponding `Array` functionality:

```
N.col(i) = pow(2.0, L.col(i).array()) + 1.0;
```

Beware that Eigen starts indexing at 0, and Matlab starts at 1, so you may need to replace `i` by `i-1`.